# PHP: Issue looping through associative array

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following associative array called `$woo_post_category`:

```
array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#5839 (10) { ["term_id"]=> int(796) ["name"]=> string(20) "Womens Comfort Bikes" ["slug"]=> string(20) "womens-comfort-bikes"
```

I'm attempting to loop through the array and pull out the value association for the name key. I have the following code:

```
foreach($woo_post_category as $key_category => $value_category) {
        if ( $key_category == 'name') {
            echo 'Product is in Category:' . ' ' . $value_category;
        }
}
```

I get the error :

> PHP Catchable fatal error:  Object of class stdClass could not be
>   converted to string

Can anyone point out the issue here, thanks

Comment: You can use array_key_value()...

Comment: `$value_category` is object of stdClass and you are trying to echo it. try `$value_category->term_id`.

Comment: Can you post the full array output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
foreach($woo_post_category[0] as $key_category => $value_category) {
    if ( $key_category == 'name') {
        echo 'Product is in Category:' . ' ' . $value_category;
    }
}
```

`$woo_post_category` is Array with one element, not an Object.

So, `$woo_post_category[0]` is first element of array, and this is your object.

When you use `foreach`, `$key_category` is key of array (0), and `$value_category` is value of first element, and it is `stdClass`.

So, when you try to run

```
if ( $key_category == 'name') {
```

, you compare `stdClass` (`$key_category`) and 'name'. And that why you got this error.

Answer (score 1):

In your case it seems, **$value_category** would come as object.

so you would get data in following manner

**$value_category->name**

**$value_category->term_id**

so you can correct the condition to make your script working.

in case need more help, please pass me script.

Thanks
Amit

Answer (score 1):

You've an associative array and not the single dimensional array so your if condition would be like as

```
foreach($woo_post_category as $key_category => $value_category) {
        if ( key_exists('name',$value_category)) {
            echo 'Product is in Category:' . ' ' . $value_category->name;
        }
}
```